# Неработает CopyFile C++

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <winbase.h>

int main() {
    CopyFile("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Downloads\\hax.jar", "C:\\", false);
    GetLastError();
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять почему не копирует файл в директорию.

Comment: Прав не хватает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторым параметром функции **CopyFile** нужно указывать имя файла. Т.е. в вашем случае вызов должен быть

```
CopyFile("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Downloads\\hax.jar", "C:\\hax.jar", false);
```

И желательно обрабатывать ошибки. В тексте ошибок так же может быть полезная информация, которая пригодится для отладки.